# Place output next to each other in R Markdown

Tags: r, matrix, markdown

How do I get two matrices in R Markdown to be displayed next to each other?

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r}
a <- matrix(rexp(18, rate=.1), ncol=3)
b <- matrix(rexp(4, rate=.1), ncol=2)
print(a)
print(b)
```
````

Yields (so above each other):

```
a <- matrix(rexp(18, rate=.1), ncol=3)
b <- matrix(rexp(4, rate=.1), ncol=2)
print(a)

## [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 6.034713 14.882553 31.177579
## [2,] 11.011486 8.991163 2.291942
## [3,] 8.329703 30.096870 1.215264
## [4,] 18.560846 19.846930 4.020519
## [5,] 22.563052 2.182901 2.538573
## [6,] 4.225677 8.603654 8.982184

print(b)

## [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 2.895999 1.859186
## [2,] 21.056651 27.426468
```

I'm looking for a solution that can be applied to this chunk of code in particular, rather than the entire document.

Comment: Perhaps use `xtable` or `stargazer` for table formatting (to be "prettier"). One hacky solution would be to set `keep_tex=true`, and then edit the `tex` file directly. Then you can set up two `tabular` environments within the same `table` call (like [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side)).

Comment: Following @Tad Dallas's comment, a hack that I have used is to construct a single matrix with a blank column that separates them and then add column names to distinguish the matrices. printing this out in `xtable` produces a pretty nice result.